# Android icon is too small

Tags: android, icons

My application is almost ready I only need to use the correct icon instead of the default. I have created a picture in photoshop and then resize it with Android Asset Studio http://reiszecke.github.io/AndroidAssetStudioFullsize/icons-launcher.html#foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0&foreColor=607d8b%2C0&crop=1&backgroundShape=none&backColor=ffffff%2C100&effects=none

But my icon is still much smaller than it should be and I have no idea why. I have tried to put into drawable instad of mipmap but doesn't worked. I tried it with another image but still wrong. But I have found a default android icon somewhere and with that icon it looks almost fine. I have checked the parameters of these images but it's the same as my images.

Do you know anything that could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you provide an icon for all different resolution (hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi)?

Also note the padding option in the web tool you linked. That may affect the appearance of your icon.